# pyglet update is not executing my key-selected functions

Tags: key, pyglet

I have a flightsim type game with lots of key-selected functions (using a dictionary) to be executed while the key is held down.  My functions seem  to be found by update but are not executed. Here is a stripped-down code showing the problem (whether self.function or function is used:

```
from pyglet          import image
from pyglet.gl       import *
from pyglet.graphics import TextureGroup
from pyglet.window   import key, mouse

def nomove():
    return

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):

    def ml(self): # 'move left'
        self.position = (-1,0,0)
        print(self.action,' has changed position left')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0)
        self.position = (0,0,0)
        self.action = 'no move'
        self.moving = nomove  #  movement unless key is held down
        print(type(nomove),type(self.moving))   # types function OK

        def mr(): # 'move right'
            self.position = (-1,0,0)
            print(self.action,' has changed position right')

        self.move_keys = {key.LEFT:('move left',self.ml), key.RIGHT:('move right',mr)}    # self?  
 
    def update(self, dt):
        self.moving  #  key-selected function to update self.position. no key -> nomove       
        print(f'update {self.position}  {self.action} {type(self.moving)}')
        if self.position != (0,0,0): print(self.action,' moved our position.')
        
    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol in self.move_keys: # select movement update function for while key pressed
            self.action, self.moving = self.move_keys.get(symbol)   # function alters self.position
            print(f'key pressed {self.action} {type(self.moving)} ')

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        print(f'key released after "{self.action}" {type(self.moving)}') 
        self.action = ''
        self.moving = nomove 

    def on_draw(self):       # Called by pyglet to redraw the canvas every frame
        self.clear()

def main():
    window = Window(600, 400)
    pyglet.app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output pressing left then right arrow keys:

```
update (0, 0, 0)  no move <class 'function'>
update (0, 0, 0)  no move <class 'function'>
key pressed move left <class 'method'> 
update (0, 0, 0)  move left <class 'method'>
update (0, 0, 0)  move left <class 'method'>#
key released after "move left" <class 'method'>
update (0, 0, 0)   <class 'function'>
update (0, 0, 0)   <class 'function'>
key pressed move right <class 'function'> 
update (0, 0, 0)  move right <class 'function'>
update (0, 0, 0)  move right <class 'function'>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if I add the function brackets to self.moving() it works perfectly.
adding () in other places changes the type from Function To None.